# How to map a polygon to the postgis type geometry(polygon, 4326)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, postgis

Model Block

```
package br.com.api.model;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Polygon;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "block")
public class Block {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "block_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    @Valid
    private Integer numero;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326)")
    private Polygon poligono;

}
```

I tried adding the @Type annotation but it didn't work, I tried using another data type other than Polygono but it didn't work. I don't know what else to do and I didn't find anything in the documentation that could help me.

Comment: you can visit [How do i insert a Point / MultiPolygon in postgres ( using postgis ) with Spring data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75647932/13496635), maybe it'll be useful for you.